# iAdの実装とビルド時のViewController

Tags: xcode, iad

iAdを実装して、ビルドしてみるとStoryboardで制約したはずのImageViewやLabelのサイズが変になります。
ビルド直後は良いのですが、iAdの広告が出てくると共に、その分だけ部品が縮まります。
これらの部品を固定するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？
Storyboardを使わずに作業した方が良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

普通、iAdなどのモバイル広告を置く場合は、広告表示エリアを別にもうけ、非広告部分は、ContainerView(IB画面の右下にあるオブジェクトライブラリの部品集のなかにある)でくるむのが定石だと思います。今日、広告は、ほとんどの場合、fill rateは、90％を越える効率なので、広告取得失敗した時の為に、ダイナミックに、非広告表示エリアのサイズを変動させるような実装は、不要でしょう。

Comment: では、広告の部品を設置して、なおかつ制約をつけてビルドしたほうがいいということでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます。解決致しました。